# UTF 8 text file Error on Raspi, what is the problem?

Tags: python, raspbian, file-handling, raspberry-pi4

The problem: Sometimes when our project doesn't detect an object. The text file generated with this function becomes a UTF-8 Encoding error. Maybe I'm no expert at python but I can't seem to track where the problem lies/the source of UTF-8 error

What the function does: With the arguments of list of objects detected and their percentages, it is supposed to log into the result.txt file and speak out the detected items.

This is the code that is of concern:

```
def CountFreq(li, probs):
    freq = {}
    if len(li) > 0:
        for items in li:
            freq[items] = li.count(items)
            # print(freq)
    if not freq:
        a = str("No object detected")
        probs.append("No probabilities")
    else:
        a = str(freq)
    words = ["Object/s detected: " + a]
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
        speak(a)
        # This is log txt
        with open("result.txt", "a") as f:
            for word in words:
                f.writelines(word + " probability in order " + str(probs) + "\n")
```

Whole code snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tflite_support.task import processor
import subprocess

_MARGIN = 10  # pixels
_ROW_SIZE = 10  # pixels
_FONT_SIZE = 1
_FONT_THICKNESS = 1
_TEXT_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)  # red


def speak(a):
    subprocess.call(['espeak', '-v', 'en-gb', '-s', '120', '-p', '70', '-a', '200', a])


def CountFreq(li, probs):
    freq = {}
    if len(li) > 0:
        for items in li:
            freq[items] = li.count(items)
            # print(freq)
    if not freq:
        a = str("No object detected")
        probs.append("No probabilities")
    else:
        a = str(freq)
    words = ["Object/s detected: " + a]
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
        speak(a)
        # This is log txt
        with open("result.txt", "a") as f:
            for word in words:
                f.writelines(word + " probability in order " + str(probs) + "\n")


def visualize(
        image: np.ndarray,
        detection_result: processor.DetectionResult,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Draws bounding boxes on the input image and return it.

    Args:
      image: The input RGB image.
      detection_result: The list of all "Detection" entities to be visualize.

    Returns:
      Image with bounding boxes.
    """

    list = []
    probs = []
    for detection in detection_result.detections:
        # Draw bounding_box
        bbox = detection.bounding_box
        start_point = bbox.origin_x, bbox.origin_y
        end_point = bbox.origin_x + bbox.width, bbox.origin_y + bbox.height
        cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, _TEXT_COLOR, 3)

        category = detection.categories[0]
        category_name = category.category_name
        list.append(category_name)
        probability = round(category.score, 2)
        probs.append(probability)
        # result_text = category_name + ' (' + str(probability) + ')'
        # trying this code below
        result_text = f"{category_name} ({probability})"
        text_location = (_MARGIN + bbox.origin_x,
                         _MARGIN + _ROW_SIZE + bbox.origin_y)
        cv2.putText(image, result_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                    _FONT_SIZE, _TEXT_COLOR, _FONT_THICKNESS)

    CountFreq(list, probs)
    return image
```

EDIT for error msgs:

There is no error message in raspi other than when i open the result.txt file, it becomes a UTF-8 error. This notably happened when opencv wasnt detecting any objects in its camera. I tried fixing it by using if len(li)==0 but error still persisted when further tested.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, all lines.

Comment: Use f.write instead of f.writelines.

Comment: I'm seeing a few possible problems that I need to ask about before I can formulate an answer: 1) Are `list` and `probs` meant to have a 1-to-1 relationship by index?  If so, then why are they two separate lists instead of a dict or a single list of tuples?   2) Within `CountFreq()`, the list `words` never has more than 1 element. It will always be a single string in the form of either `"Object/s detected: No object detected"` or `"Object/s detected: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}"`  Is this intended, or did you actually mean to loop over the values in `freq` and print one result line for each?

Comment: Additional aside - while it doesn't seem to be causing your particular issue, naming a variable `list` as in your `visualize()` function is just asking for debugging headaches, as doing so overwrites the built-in function `list()` within that scope.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety
1: I never thought of it that way. must have overlooked. I was fixing the code for my teammate and decided not to change the list.

2: The word variable is meant to be for logging purposes. The array that gets printed first is the objects array while the next array is the percentage array resulting from opencv. It's intended for input in the result txt so that every snapshot detected, all of the objects/percentages are in one line from the snapshot/capture

Comment: @Don'thavetHanswers.  Ok, so then there's no reason for `words` to be a list and to loop over `for word in words`, as it always a single string.   
  Also, is the file being deleted before each test? As its only opened in Append mode, if you have an existing file with the UTF error, no change to your code is going to resolve the existing error.  The line `if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r')` also indicates to me that it might not be writing anything as its only waiting 1 millisecond to see if the user is pressing the 'r' key, and with no input, `waitKey()` returns -1.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety yes. The band aid solution we came up was to send the text file to PC using gmail through raspi OS web. eventually we saw the text.